# how to make the silverlight page to wait for few seconds

Tags: multithreading, silverlight-4.0

I build silverlight application in that I am showing progress bar before the content is loaded and I need to pass the progress bar for few seconds and then I need to close..

I am using system.threading.thread.sleep(1000) but it makes the UI to freeze.

I need alternative in silverlight where in it should not freeze the UI and process should wait for some time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default everything is on the UI thread, so any time-consuming task will block the UI.  To prevent this, push the execution to a background thread -- one way to do that is [`Task.Factory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});
```

Note that, if you then want to do anything with the UI (which I suppose you would), then you'll need to get back to the UI thread.  (If a background thread tries to change the UI, the runtime will throw an exception.)  Do that by using a [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
    // sleep on a background thread
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // when complete, return to the UI thread to prevent access violation
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {

        // do UI stuff here
    });
});
```